# Should questions with code from games be tagged [game]?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are a few games, like [TIS-100](http://www.zachtronics.com/tis-100/) that are based on programming. We've had a couple questions that ask for a review of code written in games like these, and all of them have been tagged [game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game).

I'm not sure if these questions should be tagged, and the ambiguous description of [game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) doesn't help either.

Should questions like these be tagged with [game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Code written for the [tis-100](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tis-100) game should not be tagged with [game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game). The game tag should be reserved for its typical use of developing a game of some sort. As far as Code Review is concerned, tis-100 is just another language. Adding the game tag to these questions doesn't add any information or context.

---

I just got around to removing [game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) from the [tis-100](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tis-100) questions, but someone beat me to it. [status-completed](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Answer (score -2):

Yes, questions like this should be tagged [game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game). Here is the tag excerpt for [game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game):

> For questions requesting reviews of game-themed code.

The code that is in the post is "game-themed" because it is code about and/or relating to a game.

Comment: Arguably, this might just mean the tag excerpt isn't accurate enough.

Comment: @nhgrif I completely agree. However, as it stands, [tag:game] could apply to these posts by our current definition.